# Disable Scrolling in child Recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I have a layout consists of a Parent RecyclerView with a sub Recyclerview in it

i know that it is not good to put a list inside another list but i have to so that i can use the sub list features like swiping and drag and drop

My issue is that the child Recyclerview gain focus and stops the parent from scrolling if the touch point was on it 
simply i want if the touch was vertically on the child Recyclerview
the parent scrolls up and down and if the touch was horizontal or a click then the child Recyclerview list item swipes left and right. 
Any help to achieve this?

Answer (score 47):

I finally found a solution.

Create Custom LinearLayoutManager

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);

}

// it will always pass false to RecyclerView when calling "canScrollVertically()" method.
@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Then instantiate it like this for vertical scrolling

```
CustomLinearLayoutManager customLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
```

Finally set the custom layout as layout manager of recycler view

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(customLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Works well in recyclerview. Best way to do

Comment: Perfect solution. Works well. But only for recyclerview version 23.2.0

Comment: You are awesome. I might as well start calling you Master.. Sensei

Answer (score 18):

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in the child RecyclerView

You can add

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

to your RecyclerView in XML or

```
childRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

to your RecyclerView in Java.

**EDIT:-**

`childRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` will work only in android_version>21 devices. to work in all devices use the following

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(childRecyclerView, false);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for >21 API as well.

Answer (score 16):

On your ActivityName.java, inside the onCreate() method write:

```
RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view_id);
v.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

By any means, if you are using Coordinator Layout, In case you want to simplify things, and you want to disable nested scrolling.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activitiesListRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And again you apply the same principle:
On your ActivityName.java, inside the onCreate() method write:

```
RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view_id);
v.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

So basically in XML, you have to specify the app: layout_behavior

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Comment: Solved my issue that support RecycleView were scrolling inside of ScrollView even when RecycleView was set as wrap_content. Replaced ScrollView with support NestedScrollView all works like intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

While it might not be good practice to have embedded recycler views, sometimes you cannot avoid it. Something like this might work:

```
public class NoScrollRecycler extends RecyclerView {

    public NoScrollRecycler(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public NoScrollRecycler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoScrollRecycler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style){
        super(context, attrs, style);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

        //Ignore scroll events.
        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            return true;

        //Dispatch event for non-scroll actions, namely clicks!
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This will disable the scroll event, but not the click events. Use this class for the "child" RecyclerView. You want the PARENT recyclerview to scroll, but not the child. Well this should do that, since the parent will just be the standard RecyclerView, but the child will be this custom one with no scrolling, but handles clicks. Might need to disable clicking for the parent RecyclerView.. Not sure as I have not tested this, so consider it just an example...

Also, to use this in XML (incase you didn't know) do the following:

```
<com.yourpackage.location.NoScrollRecycler
     ...
     ... >

     ...
     ...

</com.yourpackage.location.NoScrollRecycler>
```

Comment: How to use this custom recycler view for the parent recycler view i need the parent to scroll and disable scrolling in the child but also list items of the child recyclerview can be clicked

Comment: Updating answer now. It should work, test it and let me know.

Comment: And the child would be another view group? Yes, I believe so but havent tried doing this yet. I can tomorrow, but I'm wondering what the purpose of disabling the scroll for a scroll view would be? Just curious :)

Comment: @LucasCrawford

Is this child RecyclerView inside a ViewHolder? I ask because I tried this and it didn't work. 

Please see: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632204/nested-recyclerview-in-viewholder-breaks-collapsing-toolbar-layout

Comment: Hello Lucas - I have a question on your code. I have posted a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295840/inner-recyclerview-not-receiving-click-event

Comment: It will disable drag'n'drop inside the nested recyclerview, if it's required.

Answer (score 3):

you can use  `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` on sub `RecyclerView` which stops scrolling inside sub `RecyclerView`.

In my case code was

`mInnerRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` where `mInnerRecyclerView` being inner `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 2):

Ithink I'm too late but here i found the solution if it's still annoying someone:

```
    RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView); 
    findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view_id);
    v.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    sensorsRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent    event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many suggested solutions and couldn't find one that worked in my case. I have more than 1 RecyclerView inside a ScrollView using a GridLayoutManager. The result from the suggestion above resulted in the ScrollView stopping to scroll whenever I lifted my finger (it didn't glide to the top or bottom of the view when my finger was lifted over a RecyclerView)

Looking through the RecyclerView source, inside the onTouchEvent there is a call to the layout manager:

```
final boolean canScrollHorizontally = mLayout.canScrollHorizontally();
final boolean canScrollVertically = mLayout.canScrollVertically();
```

If you override these in a custom layout manager, return false and it will stop scrolling. It also fixes the problem where the ScrollView would stop scrolling abruptly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

put the code inside `LinearLayout`...no need to do anything pragmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want make a custom view, another option is to create a same sized layout in front of the RecyclerView, and make it clickable.

EDIT:
But unfortunately it blocks events for list item too.

Answer (score 0):

The `Kotlin` way:

```kotlin
recyclerView.layoutManager = object: LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.context) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```