# How to disable RecyclerView scrolling to make the layout listen its ScrollView parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to put a `RecyclerView`, inside a `ScrollView`. But the `ScrollView` doesn't scrolls and the `RecyclerView` does but I don't want it to... What can I do?

I tried with this class https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222721/4864104 and in fact the `RecyclerView` doesn't scroll anymore, but neither does the `ScrollView`.

Any help to make the `ScrollView` work even with the disabled `RecyclerView`? Thanks in advance.

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="jahirfiquitiva.projects.activities.DeveloperActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/osv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:overScrollMode="never">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoJahir"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/lists_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/lists_padding"
            android:text="@string/developer_bio"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_subtitle_material_toolbar" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dividers_about_section"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:background="@color/primary" />

        <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/buttonsGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/lists_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/lists_padding" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dividers_about_section"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:background="@color/primary" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Extend the layout manager and override some methods, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32136016/3546507

Answer (score 11):

You could easily achieve it by changing your scroll view into a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) and setting `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`
Has the highest performance and No need to override the layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap recyclerView so that other views can be visible. Just use this library so that you can adjust recycler view height coz linearLayoutManager as per now matches height to match parent.
https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager

Answer (score 0):

it not as simple as you think. when you use tow scrollble element inside each other you are in hot water! you should calculate the Recycler item height and then find the whole recycler height.
look at below link, I explain completely this problem.

[Use RecyclerView indie ScrollView with flexible recycler item height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420770/use-recyclerview-inside-scrollview-with-flexible-recycler-item-height)

I hope it help you