# Android - Double RecyclerView and CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm currently developing an App which needs to display a vertical list, with horizontal list for each child. This view is using a CoordinatorLayout (with a CollapsingToolbarLayout). The problem is that when I scroll (vertically), the Toolbar isn't collapsing.

I noticed that the problem occurs only if the vertical list's item are horizontal lists.

Here is a picture explaing my problem :

[image: RecyclerView problem]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632204/nested-recyclerview-in-viewholder-breaks-collapsing-toolbar-layout?rq=1) , using setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) on the child RecyclerView ! :)