# CollapsingToolbarLayout collapses inconsistently on RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

When using a CollapsingToolBarLayout with a RecyclerView, I found that the toolbar collapsed inconsistently when scrolling.  I could scroll about halfway through the recyclerview before anything collapsed at all, and then it would collapse in fits and starts.  The behavior wasn't always consistent - sometimes it would collapse more than others.  By the time I scrolled to the bottom, however, it was always fully collapsed.  My XML looked like the following:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" >
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try these flags and see if it fits with your desire: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"`

Comment: The problem wasn't that I wanted the snap behavior, it was that the scrolling was jerky and that the toolbar would sometimes stay partially collapsed as I continued to scroll the RecyclerView.  Fixed with the solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the ultimate issue was having a second RecyclerView within some of the view holders of the first.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632204/nested-recyclerview-in-viewholder-breaks-collapsing-toolbar-layout), setting `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on the inner RecyclerView caused things to behave as expected.