# How to disable manual scroll of Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have horizontal Recyclerview and want to disable manual scroll of it. But on click of item it should scroll. How to do it?

Comment: Please check below thread. It may helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222310/disable-scrolling-in-child-recyclerview-android

Answer (score 2):

Implement RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener in your call it stole all the touch event on recyclerview

```
public class RecyclerViewDisabler implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean) {

}
}
```

For enabling and disable the scroll :

```
RecyclerView recycleview = ...
RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener disabler = new RecyclerViewDisabler();

recycleview.addOnItemTouchListener(disabler);    // scolling disable
// do what you want to do  at time of disable scrolling
recycleview.removeOnItemTouchListener(disabler); // scrolling enabled again
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Will try.

Comment: This disables onClick also

Answer (score 2):

```
// You can set `onTouchListener`

public class RecyclerViewTouch implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

// Use it
RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener disable = new RecyclerViewTouch();
rView.addOnItemTouchListener(disable);        // disables scolling
rView.removeOnItemTouchListener(disable);     // enable the scrolling
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to create a custom layout manager for this,you can disable the scrolling in this way

**example:**

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

public CustomLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
   //Similarly you can customize "canScrollVertically()" for managing horizontal scroll
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally();
}
```

this way you can disable manual scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Emi Raz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8040697/emi-raz).
His answer is so simple for disabling scroll behaviour on recyclerview. And the solution works for me.
please see his solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53995725/4714948)

java:

```
LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

kotlin:

```
val lm: LinearLayoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean { return false }
}
```